# Show only those instances which don't have invoices for current month

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to show only those instances which don't have invoices for current month, but there is a possibility that older invoices can exist and it should not matter.

My goal is essentially to build the following

```
SELECT * FROM
 instance
WHERE 
 1=1
AND
instance.active=true
AND
 instance.id NOT IN 
 (
  SELECT instance_id FROM invoice WHERE invoice_date='2016-07-01'
 )
```

This is what I came up with and it does not work properly

```
    $instances= Instance::where('active', '=', true)->with(['invoice' => function($query) {
    $query->where('invoice_date', '!=',Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-01'));
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Dumb question.. Shouldn't it be `Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')`?

Comment: `01` is for the first day - I am marking all monthly dates as 01 :) sorry for confusion

Comment: Sorry, now I see what you're trying to do. What you should do is to get the first of the month and compare that invoice_date is less than that date. Not '!=' cause then you say only that day but the rest of the month is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, this should do it

```
    $instances= Instance::where('active', '=', true)->whereHas('invoice', function($query) {
          return $query->where('invoice_date', '<', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m').'-01');
    })->with('invoice')->get();
```

Comment: It will still show me the instances if they have any older invoices; I don't want to have instances in the data structure whatsoever. If instance id exists, do not show the instance id at all

Comment: Okey.. Though it hit me, shouldn't it be `return $query->where('invo...`

Comment: And another thing, you will still get the Instance-object but without the relation, if the query is false